# warning libgfortran.so.3 needed by may conflict with libgfortran.so.5

Tags: linux, fortran, mpi, linker-errors, gfortran

while compiling I get the following warning:

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: libgfortran.so.3, needed by /usr/openmpi-4.0.3rc4/lib64/libmpi_usempi.so, may conflict with libgfortran.so.5

It does create the .exe but when executing it an error occurs:

> ideal.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I search for it to try and link it but it didn't work

> whereis libgfortran.so.5

> libgfortran.so: /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3

I don't have much knowlegde about linux or compilers and I'm working on a SUSE server without sudo permission. The gnu fortran compiler I'm using is in my home directory /home/gomezmr/gcc . Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask] and [mcve]. In your case we are missing more details about your software environment and the installed libraries and compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OpenMPI library was compiled for a different version of GCC/gfortran than the version you are using for compiling. The MPI library must be compiled for the same compiler version that you are using for compiling.

In simple cases it may happen that it will somehow work anyway, but problems like yours can happen. When using the `mpi` or `mpi_f08` modules, the major release version must match (e.g. both GCC9 or both GCC 11,...).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how could I solve the problem? I tried to install OpenMPI on my workspace, but the same error raised when doing de configuration.

Comment: before compiling Open MPI, make sure your environment is set correctly (e.g. `libgfortran.so.5` is in your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`